# Matplotlib Qt4 GUI programming - replace plt.figure() with OO equivalent

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, qt4

I have an App made using Qt4 Designer which inserts a matplotlib figure into a container widget.

The code to generate the figure comes from another module, obspy:

```
self.st.plot(fig = self.rawDataPlot)
```

https://docs.obspy.org/packages/autogen/obspy.core.stream.Stream.plot.html
Normally, this would create and show a matplotlib figure for the `st` object's data, which is time-series.  When the `fig` parameter is specified this tells `self.st.plot` to plot to an existing matplotlib figure instance.

The code I have to generate the figure and then position it in my GUI widget is:

```
def addmpl(self, fig, layout, window):  # code to add mpl figure to Qt4 widget
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
    self.canvas.draw()
    self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, 
    window, coordinates=True)
    layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)

self.rawDataPlot = plt.figure()     # code to create a mpl figure instance  
self.st.plot(fig = self.rawDataPlot)  # plot time-series data to existing matplotlib figure instance
self.addmpl(self.rawDataPlot, self.mplvl, self.mplwindow)  # add mpl figure to Qt4 widget
```

What I want to do is instantiate a matplot figure (for use by `self.st.plot`) but in a way which avoids using `plt.figure()`, as I have read that this is bad practice when using object-oriented programming.

If I replace `plt.figure()` with `Figure()` (from matplotlib.figure.Figure()) I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'draw'
```

As it stands, the App runs fine if I use plt.figure(), but is there a clean way to avoid using is and is it even necessary for my case?

PS, the code snippets here are taken from a larger source, but I think it gets the point across..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle both methods should work. 
Whether you set `self.rawDataPlot = plt.figure()` or `self.rawDataPlot = Figure()` does not make a huge difference, assuming the imports are correct.

So the error is most probably triggered within the `self.st.plot()` function. (In general, if you report errors, append the traceback.)

Looking at the source of [`obspy.core.stream.Stream.plot`](https://docs.obspy.org/_modules/obspy/core/stream.html#Stream.plot) there is a keyword argument

> `:param draw:` If True, the figure canvas is explicitly re-drawn, which
>               ensures that *existing* figures are fresh. It makes no difference
>               for figures that are not yet visible.
>               Defaults to `True`.

That means that apparently the plot function tries to draw the canvas, which in the case of providing a `Figure()` hasn't yet been set.

A good guess would therfore be to call

```
self.rawDataPlot = Figure()
self.st.plot(fig = self.rawDataPlot, draw=False)
```

and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I also found another way which works without having to call plt.figure():
`self.rawDataPlot = self.st.plot(fig = None, handle = True)`.

Setting `handle = True` in `self.st.plot()` retrns the matplotlib figure instance instead of requiring one to already exist, as is the case for `fig = something...`